# Expressions unchanged by permuting the roots of a polynomial

Tags: group-theory, polynomials

I am trying to self-read through Ian Stewart's Galois theory and am stuck at this paragraph. I quote - "Lagrange observed that all methods for solving polynomial equations by radicals involve constructing rational functions of the roots that take a small number of values when the roots $\alpha_j$ are permuted. Prominent among these is the expression

$$\delta = \prod_{j< k} (\alpha_j - \alpha_k)$$

which takes just two values, $\pm \delta$, plus for even permutations and minus for the odd ones. Therefore, $\Delta = \delta^{2}$ is a rational function of the coefficients. This gets us started and it yields a complete solution for the quadratic."

My question is as follows: Why should an expression that is unchanged by permuting the roots of a polynomial be expressible as a rational function of the polynomial's coefficients? Is this statement even true or have I misunderstood the book?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a straightforward consequence of the [Fundamental Theorem on Symmetric Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#The_fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials). Indeed, the coefficients of the polynomial are the evaluation of the so called elementary symmetric functions at the roots.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will read the theorem and post the complete reasoning as an answer once I understand it.

Comment: @Dinesh: the first proof of the fundamental theorem at Wikipedia is, in my opinion, unreadable.  I prefer the one labeled "an alternative proof," which I believe is equivalent to the one I wrote up here: http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/08/20/introduction-to-symmetric-functions/

Comment: @QIaochu, it would take quite a bit of inventiveness to outworst that proof!